# Is a question on the current usage of academic indicators (h-index, impact factor, etc) too loose a question for Academia.SE?

Tags: discussion

I would be interested to know if anyone has **objective** facts and **reports** on how academic workplaces are currently using these academic indicators. For instance in the upcoming REF2014, academics are urged to use the papers in journals with the highest impact factors

I would not like to start a discussion on how "not representative", or how flawed, these numbers are, or generic rants.

Would that be an ok question for Academia.SE?

Answer (score 4):

That's definitely on-topic here, as this directly relates to academia, and you should state directly in the question that you don't want it to degrade to an off-topic discussion about the usefulness of the measures. I think the question can stand on it's own without having to go down that road.

Comment: thanks, posted on Academia.SE